# PHP server outputting warning about FD_SETSIZE

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu

I'm currently a newbie with PHP and MySQL, however, I'm trying to run a PHP server code for a Club Penguin Emulator, however, i am having no luck as more people join and make it incredibly hard to join due to PHP warnings and errors.

I had a open file limit which i changed by [**following this tutorial**](https://easyengine.io/tutorials/linux/increase-open-files-limit/)

However, my PHP code runs, very slowly, however, it keeps outputting this:

> socket_select(): You MUST recompile PHP with a larger value of
>   FD_SETSIZE.

It is set to 1024, but you have descriptors numbered at least as high as 1978.

`--enable-fd-setsize=2048` is recommended, but you may want to set it to equal the maximum number of open files supported by your system, in order to avoid this error at a later date.

Now my question is, how can i recompile PHP and how can i change this value?

Answer (score 0):

Use the command `wget` to download the latest php sources. You will get probably an archive or something. Unzip the archive and run the setup with your configurations.

Otherwise consult de FAQ http://php.net/manual/en/faq.build.php